# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to access NodeJS backend API from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api, connection-refused

**When i try to access my backend which runs on localhost:3000 on the same Ubuntu server as my NGINX hosted Angular site, i always get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".**

[image]

***What I have already done is:***

create a proxy.config.json file and filled it:

```
{
"/api/v1": {
    "target": "http://myIPAdress:3000/api/v1",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/v1" : ""}
}
```

Add it to angular.json:

```
"serve": {
      "options": { "port": 80, "host": "0.0.0.0", "disableHostCheck": true, "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json" },
```

Using my server IP instead of localhost because I read that does no longe word on the server:

```
registerUser(username: string, password: string, email: string){
let url="https://myIPAdress/api/v1/users/register";
return this.http.post(url, {
  "username": username,
  "email": email,
  "password": password 
})
```

Enabled CORS in the API:

```
const cors = require('cors'); //enables cross origin resources `app.use(cors());`
app.options('*', cors());
```

And it is just listening to port: 3000
**On my local machine angular and the api worked nicely together, so I guess all the code is working, and it is just a networking error.**

Sadly, none of this helped, so I am really at a loss right now.

Comment: The same using react